# Consulta MySQL, seleccionar el registro más reciente por cada empleado

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema, ojalá me puedan apoyar, actualmente tengo dos tablas, una de empleados y otra de sus movimientos, quisiera mediante una consulta MySQL obtener un listado de todos los empleados y enseguida el último movimiento por cada empleado que tenga asignado en la tabla movimientos, ¿es posible lograr eso?.
Ésta es la forma que tengo los datos almacenados

[image: Tabla Empleados]

[image: Tabla Movimientos]

El resultado que deseo obtener es para el empleado Carlos, muestre enseguida todos los datos del idMovimiento 2 (ya que es el movimiento más reciente y se encuentra dentro de la fecha actual),
para el empleado Jenny, muestre todos los datos del idmovimiento 2 (ya que se encuentra dentro de la fecha actual), y para el empleado Ana, muestre Null en todas las columnas, ya que no hay ningún movimiento asignado. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
  SELECT 
    empleados.*, movimientos.*
FROM
    bd_secjo.empleados
        LEFT JOIN
    bd_secjo.movimientos ON movimientos.idempleado = empleados.idempleado
```

> Pero me da dos registros para el empleado Carlos y solo deseo obtener el más reciente.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: ya probaste alguna consulta? podria hacer `order by idEMpleado asc, idMovimiento desc`

Comment: Estas obteniendo los movimientos de Alta y Baja. Prueba `WHERE movimiento = 'Alta'` o `WHERE movimiento = 'Baja'`.

Comment: Necesito el último movimiento, basado en la fecha de inicio y que la fecha actual se encuentre dentro del rango de fechaInicio y fechaFin

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que para poder obtener el registro mas reciente, hagas uso de una *subconsulta* para obtener la fecha mayor así:

```
WHERE movimientos.fechaInicio = (SELECT MAX(movimientos.fechaInicio) 
FROM movimientos)
```

Y posterior para ubicar la fecha actual dentro de un rango, la obtengas por medio de `current_date()` y hagas uso del operador `BETWEEN` de este modo (dado que estás diciendo que la fecha actual este entre la **fecha de inicio** y la **fecha de fin**)

```
AND current_date() BETWEEN movimientos.fechaInicio AND movimientos.fechaFin
```

Y que tu consulta luzca de este modo:

```
SELECT 
    empleados.*, 
    movimientos.*
FROM
    bd_secjo.empleados
LEFT JOIN
    bd_secjo.movimientos ON movimientos.idempleado = empleados.idempleado
WHERE movimientos.fechaInicio = (SELECT MAX(movimientos.fechaInicio) 
FROM movimientos)
AND current_date() BETWEEN movimientos.fechaInicio 
AND movimientos.fechaFin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero hay que hacer una subconsulta para encontrar el valor máximo por cada grupo de `idEmpleados` en el campo `fechaInicio` (supongo que esa es la referencia ¿no?). A esa consulta le llamaremos T2, la cual entonces se le hace JOIN con la tabla `empleados` (T1)

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM bd_secjo.empleados T1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT idEmpleado, movimiento,  MAX(fechaInicio) fechaInicio, fechaFin 
    FROM bd_secjo.movimientos 
    GROUP BY idEmpleado) T2 
ON T1.idEmpleado = T2.idEmpleado
```

Resultado

```
+----------+------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|idEmpleado|nombre|idEmpleado|movimiento|fechaInicio|fechaFin  |    
+----------+------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|1         |CARLOS| 1        |Alta      |2019-06-14 |2100-01-01|
|2         |JENNY | NULL     |NULL      |NULL       |NULL      |
|3         |ANA   | 3        |Alta      |2019-05-01 |2019-06-10|
+----------+------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, tienes que realizar un subconsulta para obtener un registro de cada grupo de movimientos por empleado:

```
select 
t1.idMovimiento, t1.idEmpleado, t1.movimiento, t1.fechaInicio, t1.fechaFin
from
(select idMovimiento, idEmpleado, movimiento, fechaInicio, fechaFin 
from movimientos
order by idEmpleado asc, fechaInicio desc) t1
group by t1.idEmpleado, t1.fechaInicio
```

Modifica el "order by" y "group by" para determinar qué registro del grupo es el que necesitas mostrar.